# Rails 4 Devise error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I am working with Rails 4.0.0.rc1/Ruby 2.0.0p195, and I am using devise at gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'.. I keep getting this error when I want to migrate to the database..

Routes File:

```
Railsapp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
end
```

development.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Error Message

> Railsapp::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to
>   updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil:
>
> @route_sets=[#]>`

Comment: are you using the devise rails4 branch?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question specifying which one I am using.

Comment: you'll probably need to update the question with your routes file

Comment: I added it to the question. Even thought I change anything in it;

Comment: I think something else is wrong --- I just created a new rails app, added devise, and migrated the database without problem. Maybe add your app to github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this problem in a brand new Rails 4 app and it was because I forgot to run

```
rails g devise:install
```

as indicated in the [Getting Started](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) section in the readme in the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) project.